# Getting data from sqlite database by calling it from Django by using HTML forms

Tags: django

I have a HTML form :

```
<form action = "" method = "get">
    <label for="movie_title">Filmo pavadinimas: </label>
    <input id="movie_title" type="text" name="movie_title">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

I want to enter the movie title and get all of the actors that casted in that movie, but I don't know how to get to that result even after reading the documentation. DB data:
[image: Database data]

Model for that table:

```
class Filmlist(models.Model):
    film_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5)  # max_digits and decimal_places have been guessed, as this database handles decimal fields as float
    length = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'film_list'
```

views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import context, loader
import sqlite3

from web.models import Filmlist
# Create your views here.
def aktoriai(request):
    print(request.GET)
    return render(request, "aktoriai.html")
```

So to conclude, I have to enter movie title and get all of those actors show under actors row. Is it possible to do that with Django and HTML?

After some amendments:
Here's my html template now:

```
<form action = "" method = "get">
    <label for="movie_title">Filmo pavadinimas: </label>
    <input type="text" name="movie_title">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<table>
{% for aktoriai in objects %}
<tr> <td>{{ aktoriai.actors }} </td> <td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import context, loader
import sqlite3

from web.models import Filmlist
# Create your views here.
def aktoriai(request):
    print(request.GET)
    objects = Filmlist.objects.filter(title=request.GET)
    return render(request, "aktoriai.html", context={'objects': objects})
```

But for some reason, when I submit i.e "AMADEUS HOLY", it doesn't return any actors :(

Comment: This is definitely possible, but the logic is likely done in the view function that handles the request.  I think it best if we see that code as well to make any answer meaningful.

Comment: Or of cousre, you could probably do this in JavaScript without a request back to the server, but...I'm not sure of your requirements.

Comment: ``objects = Filmlist.objects.filter(title=request.GET)`` I don't think this is doing what you think.  I think you need ``request.GET['movie_title']``.  But you could/should print them out in your view and see what objects are being returned by the filter.  Then play with it until it gives you the objects you think it should.  Next, I don't see any definition for ``actors``.  Is it just missing from what you posted?  I assume when you say it doesn't return any actors it means it's an empty set and not that there's some sort of exception?

Comment: @saquintes - when i use request.GET['movie_title'] it throws me an error:
Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 'movie_title'

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** I missed the part about printing the actors in each film, which this answer doesn't address.  But there's no indication of how they relate in the question, so don't know how to include it. So I'm leaving the answer as is in case the OP finds it useful, but I understand it's incomplete.

I don't have a django project setup, so this may need a bit of tweaking, and we don't have your html template, but here's the basics of what I think you would do.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import context, loader
import sqlite3

from web.models import Filmlist
# Create your views here.
def aktoriai(request):
    print(request.GET)
    objects = Filmlist.objects.filter(title=request.GET['movie_title'])
    return render(request, "aktoriai.html", context={'objects': objects})
```

Then in  `aktoriai.html` you'd loop over `objects` in order to create your table.

Comment: Hey, your comment gave me a better understanding of the topic. I tried to follow your steps, but I failed to print the actors. The question was updated with the latest code. Could you please check if my html code requires any changes?